# Build a "light" jar on multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a multi-module project which I assemble with the assembly plugin to a fat jar. Thank works fine so far, but now I want to build another jar that only consists of special packages of the dependencies of the uber-pom.

An example:

I have 3 deps on sub-projects and I want to have a jar with

- com.mycompany.api.*,
- com.mycompany.settings.*
- com.mycompany.public.*

but not

- com.mycompany.internal.*

These packages are distributed through the 3 deps.

Any chance to realize something like that with the assembly plugin?

Thanks,
 Jan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) plugin should probably be able to do something like that.

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <includes>
                    <include>com/mycompany/api/*</include>
                    <include>com/mycompany/settings/*</include>
                    <include>com/mycompany/public/*</include>
                  </includes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: @gustafc Thank you, that works. But now I have another problem. In my initial "agregator" project I used modules to build all modules and grab the outcomes (jar, sources-jar, jar-with-dependecies) from the target folders. Furthermore I grabbed some dll's from sub-modules that have been built on jenkins (using .net compiler) and I need in my distribution zip.

In my pom I started a module build and then used the assembly plugin (and the `moduleSets`section). For modules I need to use pom-packaging, but the shade plugin builds pom's as well now (and not jars) although this is a jar..Any hints?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand (or that I would be able to help if I did). You may want to post this as a separate question.